# Outlook 2003 Email Headers

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook-2003, headers

How do I view the full email headers in Outlook 2003?

Answer (score 5):

This is how to view the full header information in outlook 2003/2007.

1. Right click on the message in its mailbox and select Options (in 2007, it is "Message Options" at the bottom of the right click menu).
2. Right click in the Internet Headers box and choose Select All.
3. Right click again in the Internet Headers box and choose Copy.

You can scroll through and read it or you can continue to your favorite text editor and paste it into that for easier reading.