# View full message headers from a .msg file in Outlook 2007

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007, smtp

I've got an Outlook 2007 email message saved as a .msg file. How do I view the full SMTP headers from this message?

[Outlook 2003 Email Headers](https://superuser.com/questions/78035/outlook-2003-email-headers) is helpful, but only for messages in a mailbox, not .msg files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Open the .msg file (Double clicking
   it should open it in Outlook).
2. If you're using Outlook 2007, click on
   the small arrow at the bottom of the
   Options section of the ribbon. If
   its Outlook 2003 or below, click
   View->Options from the menu bar.
   This should bring up the Message
   Options window.
3. The full message
   headers should be present in the
   text box labeled "Internet headers"
   in this window.

Source: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/HA010937071033.aspx

Comment: Oh my God! I would never in a million years have found that by myself. Thank you.

Comment: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/HA010937071033.aspx is no longer found. In the Wayback Machine: https://web.archive.org/web/20100304131316/http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/HA010937071033.aspx

Answer (score 0):

To give a more up to date answer with a current Outlook, you can check the headers by using the *"File"* menu. This will give next screen:

[image]

The click *"Properties"* and a new window will open. You can check the headers inside there:

[image]