# Outlook 2010 - filter emails by sending server?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, headers

I want to set up a rule so that any message sent by a certain server (in my case, an internal application server that sends workflow notifications) would be placed into a subfolder. A slight issue is that `from` header is being set to the email address of the co-worker initiating the change; if I [inspect message headers](https://superuser.com/a/390808/142663), this is the information I see:

```
Received: from appserver.example.com (..)
 by mailserver.example.com (..) with Microsoft SMTP Server
...
From: coworker <coworker@example.com>
Reply-To: coworker <coworker@example.com>
Return-Path: coworker@example.com
```

So I want to dump all emails sent by `appserver.example.com` to be filtered. My SMTP terminology is lacking, but I think I *may* be after filtering by [MSA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mail_submission_agent) or [MTA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mail_transfer_agent).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use "*with **specific words** in the **message header***" condition by adding

"*Received: from appserver.example.com*" (without quotes)

as a required phrase.