# Where does outlook get data for 'Mileage' Field

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, powershell, exchange

Currently I am creating a Powershell script to send emails although I need to send through a value in the 'Mileage' field.

The email sends fine, although I cannot work out how to add data for the 'Mileage' Field. On inspection it appears this field isnt given in the header. So I would assume that it has to be a HTML tag or something.

If outlook doesnt get this information from the header. where does it get it from? This information may enable me to add it to my message

Thank you

Comment: [Tracking Your Email Mileage](http://windowsitpro.com/exchange-server/tracking-your-email-mileage) might help ...

Comment: This didnt prove that useful. Thank you for your assistance however

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [display internal data of Outlook item](https://superuser.com/q/390806/287473) and check in them. – Do not concentrate on message source, but **save all MIME attachments**: In that answer, please note the registry key `SaveAllMIMENotJustHeaders`. This can help you to see other parts of the message.

If you won't find it in other MIME parts of the message, then it is possible that it is stored in binary parts of the message, what means that these properties are preserved only inside MS Exchange server, but are stripped if message is sent to server of another type.

You can then always view the MAPI storage (e.g. using [mfcmapi](https://mfcmapi.codeplex.com/) tool) to learn more about storage details.

Comment: Maybe I was a little unclear in my question, Im sorry for this. I want to know how outlook gets this data. As it is not in the header, how is this information sent through an email?

Comment: Hello, After trying your solution, I have found that I am unable to view the source of a test email (With the milage set). I've researched and found this could be due to the email being in .txt format. This is even more confusing as to where outlook is getting this data!

Comment: @user3012508 – Send a round-trip email to some different e-mail server (e.g. Apache) and back. If the mileage information gets lost, it means it is preserved only inside Exchange server storage. If it is only inside the Exchange, I think I can help you too, if you are interested.

Comment: Good plan, I shall have to try this

Comment: It seems like you are correct. Forwarding the test email to the 'outside' world and back again removes the milage.